# How not to return a response in BadRequest when using Type Filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Type Filters to log data from my API. Here is an example of what my Action Method looks like:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[TypeFilter(typeof(LoggingFilter))]
public async Task<IActionResult> MethodAction(Model model)
{
   try
   {
      //Some logic, including logging
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      return BadRequest();
   }
}
```

How can I log the Exception without passing it into BadRequest?

I have tried searching for a way without having to log it directly from the controller as that would defeat the purpose of `LoggingFilter`. I would like to log the Exception from the `LoggingFilter` without having to return the error response.

Comment: Have a look at [exception filters and exception handling middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#exception-filters)